# how can i create resizable widgets in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, window-resize

i am working on a project using PyQt5 and i want to make sure that the widgets are resizable by the user >

what do i mean ?

this is a picture explains the meaning :

[image]

i want to make the user be able to resize each widget or make the left bigger the the right by his mouse control

i am very sorry because i do not know how to write a code make you close to the result ,  because i am not close at all ... but i wrote a code to try on :

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.resize(800,500)
window_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()



first_widget = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
first_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(0,150,0)")



second_widget = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
second_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(150,0,0)")



window_layout.addWidget(first_widget,0,0)
window_layout.addWidget(second_widget,0,1)
window.setLayout(window_layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

thanks

Comment: Use [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer to my question.

but first i want to thank **mahkitah** user whom help me to find the solution.

here is my code.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.resize(800,500)
window_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()



first_widget = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
first_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(0,150,0)")



second_widget = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
second_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(150,0,0)")



splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter()
splitter.addWidget(first_widget)
splitter.addWidget(second_widget)


window_layout.addWidget(splitter)
window.setLayout(window_layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```